How Ambari manages Apache hadoop
Ambari is an open source project, but HDP is no longer available for download, so how does Ambari manage components such as Apache Hadoop, Hive, and Spark? Can Ambari directly manage existing Hadoop clusters?
I've finished installing ambari and booted it successfully
At the same time, Apache Hadoop, Hive and other components are also installed
How do I get Ambari to manage and monitor my open source cluster?
I already have data on my current Hadoop cluster and don't want to rebuild a new cluster. Or is there another similar Ambari tool that provides management of existing clusters?
I hope someone can provide answers, thank you very much.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
